# red5 v0.9: how can i log information to log file?

Tags: log4j, red5

I'm reading this tutorial on how to build my project project using eclipse with the red5 eclipse plugin. the problem is that this tutorial is for version 0.6 and i have version 0.9.

the tutorial is at:
http://www.actionscript.org/resources/articles/615/1/Getting-started-with-red5-server/Page1.html

On page 2 that tutorial explains about logging information to the log file using the following imported classes:

```
import org.apache.commons.logging.Log; 
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
```

then the tutorial explains to add the jar red5/lib/commons-logging-1.1.jar to the 
build path of eclipse but the problem is that this file does not exist.

the only jar files that contain the word log are:

1. log4j-over-slf4j-1.5.8.jar
2. logback-classic-0.9.17.jar
3. logback-core-0.9.17.jar

what exactly do i do to log using red5 0.9 ?
thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok red5 0.9 just uses log4j. 
needed to import import org.apache.log4j.Logger; after adding log4j-over-slf4j-1.5.8.jar to the external jars list in eclipse.

good log4j tutorial:
http://www.laliluna.de/log4j-tutorial.html

Comment: it seems that red5 also supports logback

Answer (score 2):

make sure you have the folder 
Program Files\Red5\logs

in that folder you place an empty file called red5.log

now in your java, every time you want a line to be written in your logfile you write

log.error( "Your description ");

if you want to pass variables to the logfile (to see the value)

log.error( "reading file : " + filename  );

All of this does not need imports of any kind. Red5 logging is already in there !

Answer (score 1):

This [link](http://www.red5.org/wiki/Documentation/Tutorials/LoggingSetup) from the Red5 website provides some more detailed instructions in order to get logging working with version 0.9 of the Red5 server.